# Setting new lines and adding them to a list to be drawn

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method that basically passes in a known drawn line segment in my view and then draws parallel lines n distances away from the passed in original line. This one in particular draws two parallel lines on either side.

It seems to be a lot of repeat code here, so how can I refactor it to a smaller method and avoid redundancy?

```
public List<Line> DrawTwoParallelLines(Line line)
   {
       List<Line> listOfParallelLines = new List<Line>(); 

       Line parallelLine1 = new Line(); 
       Line parallelLine2 = new Line();
       Line parallelLine3 = new Line();
       Line parallelLine4 = new Line();

       parallelLine1.point1.x =(float)(line.point1.x + 50 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine1.point1.y = (float)(line.point1.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine1.point2.x = (float)(line.point2.x + 50 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine1.point2.y = (float)(line.point2.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));

       parallelLine2.point1.x = (float)(line.point1.x + 100 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine2.point1.y = (float)(line.point1.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine2.point2.x = (float)(line.point2.x + 100 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine2.point2.y = (float)(line.point2.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));

       parallelLine3.point1.x = (float)(line.point1.x + -50 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine3.point1.y = (float)(line.point1.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine3.point2.x = (float)(line.point2.x + -50 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine3.point2.y = (float)(line.point2.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));

       parallelLine4.point1.x = (float)(line.point1.x + -100 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine4.point1.y = (float)(line.point1.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine4.point2.x = (float)(line.point2.x + -100 * Math.Cos(90));
       parallelLine4.point2.y = (float)(line.point2.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));

       listOfParallelLines.Add(parallelLine1);
       listOfParallelLines.Add(parallelLine2);
       listOfParallelLines.Add(parallelLine3);
       listOfParallelLines.Add(parallelLine4);

       return listOfParallelLines;

   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you know about radians?

`Math.Cos` (and the other trig functions in .Net) are based on radians not degrees.

`Math.Cos(90)` radians is roughly `Math.Cos(5157)` in degrees. Which is a bit odd...

There are `2π` radians in a circle so 1 degree is `π/180`. As long as you use the same value the lines will be parallel anyway but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Why do you need the Cos at all?

You have a line from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) with length `L = Math.Sqrt((x1-x2)^2 +(y1-y2)^2)`.

You know that you need to offset the line by an amount (`offset`) orthogonal to the current line.

```
private Line CreateParallelLine(Line target, int offset)
{
    var parallelLine = new Line();
    var xDifference = target.point1.x - target.point2.x;
    var yDifference = target.point1.y - target.point2.y;
    var length = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xDifference, 2) + Math.Pow(yDifference, 2));

    parallelLine.point1.x = target.point1.x - offset * yDifference/length;
    parallelLine.point2.x = target.point2.x - offset * yDifference/length;
    parallelLine.point1.y = target.point1.y + offset * xDifference/length;
    parallelLine.point2.y = target.point2.y + offset * xDifference/length;

    return parallelLine;
}
```

Edit:

I realised that I've only given you an opportunity to create a single parallel line but I think it's straightforward to call the method more times with different offsets!

You didn't show your `Line` class/struct but it's worth noting that `point1` should be at least PascalCase (`Point1`) but preferably renamed to something more like: `Start` and `point2` renamed to be `End` or similar.

As `x` and `y` are also public, you should PascalCase them too: `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Ah so all public variables should be in Caps? And how come Math.cos(90) worked? I tried that to get at a right angle to the original line. So I don't need to do that?

Comment: @KalaJ They should be properties. You should never use public fields. I'm not convinced your solution does work - try it with a line with no change in y e.g. (1,1), (5, 1). I'm almost 100% sure your code won't work.

Comment: It works just fine. I tried it (otherwise I would not post this here).

Comment: @KalaJ A line of (200, 1) to (400, 1) will result in the parallel lines being drawn on top of the original line. They are parallel but you aren't positioning them in the right place (you are only translating the x coordinate).

Comment: Very good catch! I'll give it a try

Comment: Actually I would prefer to call the method once but return a list of lines to be drawn in the screen. Or does it not matter? So in the case of generating multiple lines and having in them a list, my approach above in my OP isn't the best. How should I shorten that?

Comment: E.g. in my method where I am actually drawing the lines, http://pastebin.com/biakruSM, There is still too much repeat code.

Comment: @KalaJ - feel free to ask a new question with your updated code. That will be easier than using the comments to discuss it :)

Comment: see this new question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91417/after-creating-parallel-lines-i-call-a-method-to-draw-the-parallel-lines

Answer (score 5):

I would say that Heslacher's idea to use a copy constructor is a good direction, but that has two arguments, doesn't have a descriptive name, and violates the *Do one thing* principle as it copies a line and then shifts the copy.

My suggestion is to separate those responsibilities:

```cs
Line(Line source)
{
    point1.x = source.point1.x;
    point1.y = source.point1.y;
    point2.x = source.point2.x;
    point2.y = source.point2.y
}

void ShiftHorizontally(float adjustment)
{
    point1.x += + adjustment;
    point2.x += adjustment;
}
```

So the usages are more readable and understandable:

```cs
public List<Line> DrawTwoParallelLines(Line line)
{
    List<Line> listOfParallelLines = new List<Line>(); 

    double cos = Math.Cos(90d);  
    float factor50 = (float)(50 * cos);
    float factor100 = (float)(100 * cos);

    listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line).ShiftHorizontally(factor50));
    listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line).ShiftHorizontally(factor100));
    listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line).ShiftHorizontally(-factor50));
    listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line).ShiftHorizontally(-factor100));

    return listOfParallelLines;
}
```

The name `ShiftHorizontally` documents what is happening and you are forced to understand only one parameter instead of two.

I also recommend **The Clean Coder: A Code of Conduct for Professional Programmers** by **Robert Cecil Martin** to learn more about clean code.

Comment: Good point about `Do one thing`.

Answer (score 3):

- Instead of calculating Math.Cos(90) 16 times, you should calculate it once and reuse it.
- Instead of assigning like

  ```
  parallelLine4.point1.y = (float)(line.point1.y + 0 * Math.Cos(90));
  ```

  you could simply use

  parallelLine4.point1.y = line.point1.y;

---

Basically I would add a `CopyConstructor` with an additional `xAdjustment` parameter to the `Line` class like

```
public class Line
{
    public Line(Line source, float xAdjustment)
    {
        point1.x = source.point1.x + xAdjustment;
        point1.y = source.point1.y;
        point2.x = source.point2.x + xAdjustment;
        point2.y = source.point2.y
    }
    // the rest of your code here
}
```

and refactor the shown method to

```
public List<Line> DrawTwoParallelLines(Line line)
   {
       List<Line> listOfParallelLines = new List<Line>(); 

       double cos = Math.Cos(90d);  
       float factor50 = (float)(50 * cos);
       float factor100 = (float)(100 * cos);

       listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line, factor50));
       listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line, factor100));
       listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line, -factor50));
       listOfParallelLines.Add(new Line(line, -factor100));

       return listOfParallelLines;

   }
```

---

A methodname like `DrawTwoParallelLines` implies that there would be some drawing action. So better rename it to something which is more clear so that **<s>Bob</s> Sam the maintainer** won't be surprised by the code inside the method.

Comment: where x in Line class is the xAdjustment right

Comment: Right. Updated.

Comment: Hmm and I thought Bob was a *builder*...

Comment: Right @Mat'sMug I forgot it's name. It should be **Sam the maintainer**.

Answer (score 3):

**Design**

This is a heavily-hardcoded function, as RobH and Heslacher have mentioned. There's no way to change the distance between the lines. Consider parameterizing this function so that it is more flexible for future use.#

Secondly I recommend returning a collection interface, depending on the functionality you wish to allow users of this function. I would typically recommend `IEnumerable<Line>` which means it can be iterated over, but cannot be modified, since you're expecting users to execute this method to create new parallel lines, but it depends on the rest of your implementation and intentions.

**Style**

*As with all style pointers, this is optional, but I do recommend it.*

Use implicit typing (the `var` keyword) when the right-hand side of a declaration makes the type obvious.

e.g.

```
List<Line> listOfParallelLines = new List<Line>();
```

Should be

```
var listOfParallelLines = new List<Line>();
```

**Naming**

Avoid putting the type of a variable in its name. That's kind of what the type declaration is for, and if you change the type later (say, to a `Collection`, or `IEnumerable`) and you forget to rename the variable, it will make for some confusing code.

Instead I would recommend:

```
var parallelLines = new List<Line>();
```

Comment: Actually that's a first. I haven't heard that one before, why is var better than List<Line>?

Comment: As I say, it's a stylistic choice, so it is optional, but by using `var` you make  it easier to change the type of `listOfParallelLines` later, by only having to change it in one place on your line. It also shortens the length of the line, and can help line up a block of declarations.